# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str in Pt[]

Tags: python, typeerror

Why does this error show up?

```
File Parser.py", line 214, in writeData
comments = subItem['Comments']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Short stacktrace:

```
213:             for subItem in Pt['C']:
214:                comments = subItem['Comments']
```

The code:

```
Pt[] is defined as is a list.
Pt = self.createPatient()

def createPatient(self):
    Pt = {
        'S' : {},
        'C' : []
    }
    return Pt

And 'C' is:
```

### #

here is a larger sample of the definition of 'C' (of Formats).
Format is a dictionary of lists.  Does this help to see?

```
Formats = {
...
    ['For Future Use', 11, ''],
],
'C' : [
    ['use', 1, ''],
    ['Call', 15, ''],
    ['Leg', 1, '1'],
    ['Rank', 1, 'A'],
    ['DateTime Entered', 14, ''],
    ['User ID', 11, ''],
    ['Comments', 255, ''],
    ['Narrative ID', 11, ''],
    ['For Future Use', 11, ''],
],
'R' : [
    ['Use', 1, ''],
    ['Call #', 15, ''],
    ['Leg', 1, '1'],
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub elements of C are still lists, which need to be accessed by their index.
To do what you want, the nicest way is to replace your lists in 'C' by dictionnaries.

So use the following instead

```
{
  'DateTime Entered' : [ 14, ''],
  'User ID' : [11, ''],
  'Comments' : [ 255, '']
}
```

And your two lines of code at the top will work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have defined `subItem` as a string somewhere earlier in your code instead of as a dictionary.  Check you definition of

```
subItem = ....
```

and I am guessing it is a string.

Comment: subItem is an instance of Pt['C'] as in for-each subItem in Pt['C']